# How can I make div popup instead of options in '<select>?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, controls

I need to implement the following control:

[image]

Also the combobox must be editable;

I need slider to be dropped down instead of options list.

Is there any library/code snippet to implement this kind of functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any library or code snippet exists with the same functionality, however, if I were you and I couldn't found any stuff, then I'd make a `textbox` for entering the number, following by an `arrow` icon, like your screenshot. Then on `$("#arrow").click(...` I would toggle the `Slider` to appear and disappear. I guess that should works.